# Why do i keep getting an error

Tags: c#, loops

For this code I keep getting an error. When I get to enter "A" it does display "please enter amount made", then it shows an error.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string SalesPerson;
    int Sales = 0;

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the salesperons's initial");
    SalesPerson = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

    while (SalesPerson !="Z")
    {

        if (SalesPerson=="A")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter amount of a sale Andrea Made");
            Sales = Convert.ToInt32(SalesPerson);   
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What language is that, C#? Please edit your question and add the relevant tag. And I doubt this error is about loops, so that tag might also be wrong. You also have some indentation problem. Moreover, the title is not useful to identify your question, and you are not showing the exact error message, nor is this a [mcve]. Please take some time to improve your question!

Comment: How huge is the error, and what is the crux of it?

Comment: Please see the marked duplicate, an equally overly-broad question of the exact same nature. Note that in your code, you _know_ the value of `SalesPerson` is `"A"`. What _integer_ value do you expect `Convert.ToInt32()` to convert that to? What makes you think that's even a valid conversion to make?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing strings and integers. Sales is an int, SalesPerson is a string and, in the case you describe, "A".

So, when you try this:

```
Sales = Convert.ToInt32(SalesPerson);
```

...it fails, because "A" (the value of the SalesPerson string) cannot be converted to an integer. The "huge" error is probably basically telling you this.

Answer (score -3):

You could try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string SalesPerson;
        int Sales = 0;

        //The loop to ask the user for a letter

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the salesperons's initial");
            SalesPerson = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

            //If the letter is not equal to "A", repeat the prompt

            }while (SalesPerson != "A")

            if (SalesPerson=="A")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter amount of a sale Andrea Made");
                Sales = Convert.ToInt32(SalesPerson);


        }
    }
```